# Find a pattern within two or more sets of text

Tags: php, pattern-matching

I have lots of data that I need to search through for certain patterns.

Problem is when looking for said patterns I have no reference to what I'm looking for.

Or in other words, I have two paragraphs. Each on similar topics. I need to be able to compare both paragraphs and find patterns. Phrases said in both paragraphs and how many times both were said.

Can't seem to find the solution because `preg_match` and other functions your required to supply the things your looking for.

**Example paragraphs**

Paragraph 1:

> Bee Pollen is made by honeybees, and is the food of the young bee. It
>   is considered one of nature's most completely nourishing foods as it
>   contains nearly all nutrients required by humans. Bee-gathered pollens
>   are rich in proteins (approximately 40% protein), free amino acids,
>   vitamins, including B-complex, and folic acid.

Paragraph 2:

> Bee Pollen is made by honeybees. It is required for the fertilization
>   of the plant. The tiny particles consist of 50/1,000-millimeter
>   corpuscles, formed at the free end of the stamen in the heart of the
>   blossom, nature's most completely nourishing foods. Every variety of
>   flower in the universe puts forth a dusting of pollen. Many orchard
>   fruits and agricultural food crops do, too.

So from those examples these patterns:

> Bee Pollen is made by honeybees

and:

> nature's most completely nourishing foods

Both phrases are found in both paragraphs.

Comment: Explode somehow your paragraphs and search for exploded parts of each paragraph in other paragraph.

Comment: does it have a specific html structure? else not really...

Comment: Do you at least have some example paragraphs?

Comment: Sure, ill post some. Thanks for your help so far!

Comment: Thank you for adding the example text and expected output! It really helps to see what it is that you're after.. Anyway, I've provided some code and explanation down below using `preg_*` a couple of times and some simple(ish)/basic(ish) array filtering which will output your expected results :) Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

This is potentially a complex question depending on whether you're looking for similar phrases or phrases that match word for word.

Finding exact *word-for-word* matches is quite simple all you need to do is split on common breaks like punctuation marks (e.g. `.,;:`) and perhaps on conjunctions as well (e.g. `and or`). However, the problem comes when you come to, for example, *adjectives* two phrases might be exactly the same but have one word different, like so:

```
The world is spinnnig around its axis at a tremendous speed.
The world is spinning around its axis at a magnificent speed.
```

This won't match because `tremendous` and `magnificent` are used in place of one another. Potentially you could work around this, however, that would be a more complex question.

## Answer

If we stick to the *simple* side of things we can achieve phrase matching with just *a few* lines of code (**4** in this example; not including the formatting for comments/readability).

```
$wordSplits = 'and or on of as'; //List of words to split on
preg_match_all('/(?<m1>.*?)([.,;:\-]| '.str_replace(' ', ' | ', trim($wordSplits)).' )/i', $para1, $matches1);
preg_match_all('/(?<m2>.*?)([.,;:\-]| '.str_replace(' ', ' | ', trim($wordSplits)).' )/i', $para2, $matches2);
$commonPhrases = array_filter( //Removes blank $key=>$value pairs
                    array_intersect( //Finds matching paterns
                        array_map(function($item){
                            return(strtolower(trim($item))); //Cleans array for $para1 values - removes leading and following spaces
                        }, $matches1['m1']),
                        array_map(function($item){
                            return(strtolower(trim($item))); //Cleans array for $para2 values - removes leading and following spaces
                        }, $matches2['m2'])
                    )
                );


var_dump($commonPhrases);
/**
OUTPUT:

array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(31) "bee pollen is made by honeybees"
  [5]=>
  string(41) "nature's most completely nourishing foods"
}
/*
```

The above code will find matches splitting both on punctuation (defined in `[...]` of the `preg_match_all` pattern) it will also concatenate the word list (matching only words in the word list with a preceding and following space).

### Wordlist

You can change the word list to include any breaks you like, editing the list until you get the phrases you are after, examples:

```
$wordSplits = 'and or';
$wordSplits = 'and but if or';
$wordSplits = 'a an as and by but because if in is it of off on or';
```

### Punctuation

You can add any punctuation marks you like into the list (between `[` and `]`), however remember that some characters do have special meanings and may need to be escaped (or placed appropriately): `-` and `^` should become `\-` and `\^` or be placed where their *special meaning* doesn't come into play.

You may consider changing:

```
([.,;:\-]|
```

To:

```
([.,;:\-] | //Adding a space before the pipe
```

So that you only split punctuation marks which are followed by a space. For example: this would mean that items like `50,000` won't be split.

### Spaces and breaks

You may also consider changing the spaces to `\s` so that `tabs` and `newlines` etc are included and not just spaces. Like so:

```
'/(?<m1>.*?)([.,;:\-]|\s'.str_replace(' ', '\s|\s', trim($wordSplits)).'\s)/i'
```

This would also apply to:

```
([.,;:\-]\s|
```

If you decide to go down that route.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on this code, don't know if it suits your needs... Feel free to expand it!

```
$p1 = "Bee Pollen is made by honeybees, and is the food of the young bee. It is considered one of nature's most completely nourishing foods as it contains nearly all nutrients required by humans. Bee-gathered pollens are rich in proteins (approximately 40% protein), free amino acids, vitamins, including B-complex, and folic acid.";
$p2 = "Bee Pollen is made by honeybees. It is required for the fertilization of the plant. The tiny particles consist of 50/1,000-millimeter corpuscles, formed at the free end of the stamen in the heart of the blossom, nature's most completely nourishing foods. Every variety of flower in the universe puts forth a dusting of pollen. Many orchard fruits and agricultural food crops do, too.";

// Strip strings of periods etc.
$p1 = strtolower(str_replace(array('.', ',', '(', ')'), '', $p1));
$p2 = strtolower(str_replace(array('.', ',', '(', ')'), '', $p2));

// Extract words from first paragraph
$w1 = explode(" ", $p1);

// Build search string
$search = '';
$found = array();


foreach ($w1 as $word) {
    //echo 'Word: ' . $word . "<br />";
    $search .= ' ' . $word;
    $search = trim($search);

    //echo '. . Search string: '. $search . "<br /><br />";

    if (substr_count($p2, $search)) {
        $old_search = $search;
        $num_occured = substr_count($p2, $search);
        //echo " . . . found!" . "<br /><br /><br />";
        $add = TRUE;
    } else {
        //echo " . . . not found! Generating new search string: " . $word . '<br />';
        if ($add) {
            $found[] = array('pattern' => $old_search, 'occurences' => $num_occured);
            $add = FALSE;
        }
        $old_search = '';
        $search = $word;
    }
}

print_r($found);
```

The above code finds occurences of patterns from the first string in the second one.
I'm sure it can be written better, but since it's past midnight (local time), I'm not as "fresh" as I'd like to be...

[Codepad-link](http://codepad.org/ukkE0khY)